# Backbone multi routers trap - sub router handler doesent invoke

Tags: backbone.js

got in trap with Backbone Router. Imagine, i have 2 Backbone Routers:

1) RootRouter - has only one route and the only responsibility - load subRouters with RequireJS and instance it.

```
var RootRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*all': 'invokeSubModule'
    },
    invokeSubModule: function(route, args) {
        require(['SubRouter'], function(subRouter) {
            new subRouter()
        })
    }
});
```

2) SubRouter - standard BB router with routes hash and handlers.

```
var SubRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'some/bar': 'doBar',
        'some/foo': 'doFoo'
    },
    doBar: function() { ... },
    doFoo: function() { ... }
});
```

I start the application from `some/bar` URL. 
On start `RootRouter` instancing and `Backbone.History` starts. 
As expected `RootRouter` - match any URL and fire `invokeSubModule` - async load and `SubRouter` instancing works as expected, but the problem is associated with `some/bar` `SubRouter` handler does not firing as page URL has not changed from last `route`.

Looking for solution i've found answers only for the case u load sub routers before history start, but it useless in my case.

So after some digging i've found solution - extend Backbone.Route and override `route` method to make possible to invoke handler if the `Backbone.getHash()` is equal to the route method operate with.

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
     route: function(route, name, callback) {
        ...
        if (!callback) callback = this[name];

        /* run handler immediately if route we add is the current URL fragment */
        if(routeRegexp.test(Backbone.history.getHash()) ) {
            this.execute(callback, this._extractParameters(routeRegexp, routeStr));
        }

        Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
            ....
        });

        return this;
    }
})
```

So i'm confused that this just a hack and may cause possible bugs in future. 
So looking for best practice how to resolve such issue and critic of my solution.

Also expect as possible answer how to manage routers lazy loading without RootRouter, as in this case first `route` will not be fired.

Comment: Did you try to subscribe to your `RootRouter` `route` event like this: `RootRouter.on("route:invokeSubModule", function(url) { SubRouter.navigate(url); })`?

Comment: it wont work because `navigate` wont trigger callback as the fragments still same. Current solution works, but i'm not sure it doesent breaks backbone ideas and its not bicycle invented again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to replicate the behavior you need without hacking the internals of backbone routing, but i have to do some stuff in the initialization.

first i will create the main router and start backbone history in with silent option = true

```
var mainRouter = new RootRouter();
Backbone.history.start({silent: true});
```

this will start backbone history, but without routing the current url.
then i got the current fragment and saved it for later use, then navigated to the base url, then back to the original fragment

```
var fragment = Backbone.history.fragment;
mainRouter.navigate('reset',true);
mainRouter.navigate(fragment, true);
```

the bad side of this approach is that you need to do 2 routing on start up

UPDATE:

below the full sample

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> sample </title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

  <script>
    var RootRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*all': 'invokeSubModule',
        'reset': 'invokeSubModule',
    },
    invokeSubModule: function(route, args) {
        new SubRouter();
    },

    navigate: function () {
                Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate.apply(this, arguments);
            },

    execute: function(callback, args) {
                console.log('execute root');
                Backbone.Router.prototype.execute.apply(this, arguments);
                console.log ('current fragment ' + Backbone.history.fragment);
            }
    });

    var SubRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'some/bar': 'doBar',
        'some/foo': 'doFoo'
    },

    navigate: function () {
                Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate.apply(this, arguments);
            },
    execute: function(callback, args) {
                console.log('execute sub');
                Backbone.Router.prototype.execute.apply(this, arguments);
                console.log ('current fragment ' + Backbone.history.fragment);
            },
    doBar: function() { 
        $('#content').html('').append('<p>BAR</p>'); 
    },
    doFoo: function() { 
        $('#content').html('').append('<p>FOO</p>'); 
    }
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var mainRouter = new RootRouter();
        Backbone.history.start({silent: true});
        var fragment = Backbone.history.fragment;
        mainRouter.navigate('#',true);
        mainRouter.navigate(fragment, true);

        $('a').click(function(){
            mainRouter.navigate($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a id='home' href="#">home</a></br>
    <a id='foo' href="#/some/foo">foo</a></br>
    <a id='bar' href="#/some/bar">bar</a></br>
    <div id='content'>HOME</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: but this approach will also force me to reset history on every module load?

Comment: no you don't have to reset on each module load, i just navigate to the reset route on the document ready event, so i am sure that sub-router is loaded before loading the sub-view, you can check fragment variable to get the correct sub-router loaded

Comment: i will update the answer with full code for you to test

Comment: Thanks, got your idea, accept as alternative solution.